# onClick button calling a method of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have a button in one of my components. By clicking it I want to render all the items of a list on the page. Without the button if i just write {this.functionName}, I can see all the items on the page
but when i write

```
<input type="submit" value="press" onClick={this.functionName} />
```

I cant see anything. I tried to bind it to this in different ways and didn't work.
Also i thought i might move the button to the homepage and under 
`<Component/>`

```
<input type="submit" value="press" onClick={Component.functionName} />
```

However it didnt work. the only thing that i noticed by replacing `Component.functionName` by `console.log('sth')` is that without clicking any refresh, "sth" prints to the console

I have already checked the site, and tried any answer that i could find but it didn't work.
The component is :

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
mixins: [
    Reflux.listenTo(TopicStore, 'onChange')
],
getInitialState: function(){
    return{
     topics: []
    }
},  

render: function(){
    return <div className="list-group">
    TopicList
    {this.renderTopics()}

</div>
},

renderTopics: function(){
    return this.state.topics.map(function(topic){
        return <li>
            {topic}
        </li>
    });
},
```

this one works fine and lists all the items in the topics on the page
but if i replace `{this.renderTopics}`with the "input" one doesnt work any more

Comment: some code buddy

Comment: i added the lines of codes

Comment: this actually could be refering to the button object not the componet

Comment: but even when i moved it to the home page and called the actual component it didnt work

Comment: try to bind to the scope like this : this.functionName.bind(this)

Comment: hope you are not using it in an anonymous function

Comment: could you provide the code for `this.functionName`? Looks like you have an array and not a function, if it renders as you say.

Comment: @OlehZiniak added the code

Answer (score 1):

use button instead of input and use bind

```
<button type="submit" value="press" onClick={this.functionName.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: button doesnt work i have already tried that, however tried that again a u suggested, still not working

Answer (score 0):

OK, without diving deep into your code, I suggest you to try something like this

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
mixins: [
    Reflux.listenTo(TopicStore, 'onChange')
],

showTopics: false,

getInitialState: function(){
    return{
     topics: []
    }
},  

render: function(){
    return (
        <div className="list-group">
          TopicList
          <button onClick={this.toggleTopics()}>Show Topics</button>
          {this.showTopics && this.renderTopics()}
       </div>
    )
},

toggleTopics: function() {
    this.showTopics = !this.showTopics;
},

renderTopics: function(){
    return this.state.topics.map(function(topic){return <li>{topic}</li>});
},
```

Watch out that trailing comma at the end, I tried to keep the structure of the code you've provided at the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your component is not displaying the topics because the input button's `onClick` method generates the list but doesn't re-render the component.

Your component's state should have a toggle to display the list (or not display). The input's `onClick` should toggle the component's state which will lead to the component being re-rendered.

```
class TopicList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showTopics: false
    }
    this.toggleTopics = this.toggleTopics.bind(this)
  }

  toggleTopics() {
    this.setState({showTopics: !this.state.showTopics})
  }

  renderTopics() {
    return this.props.topics.map(x => 
      <li key={x}>{x}</li>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <input type='submit' value='press' onClick={this.toggleTopics} />
      <ul>
        {this.state.showTopics && this.renderTopics()}
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, don't forger to give the `li` tags a `key` property.